# Changing properties of a Javascript object from string to int

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, parseint

I have an array of objects with three properties each (year, total, per_capita).
Example:

```
0: Object
  per_capita: "125.8"
  total: "1007.2"
  year: "2009"
```

Those properties are strings and I want to create a loop that goes through the array and converts them to int.
I tried the following loop:

```
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    parseInt(data[i].year, 10)
    parseInt(data[i].total, 10)
    parseInt(data[i].per_capita, 10)
}
```

However when I do typeof(data[0].total) it says its a string.
I am having problems later in the program and I think it is because the values cannot be computed properly because they are not the right type.
Anyone have an idea where the problem is?

Comment: really int not float? you are loosing precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) does not mutate objects but parses a string and returns a integer. You have to re-assign the parsed values back to the object properties.

```
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    data[i].year = parseInt(data[i].year, 10)
    data[i].total = parseInt(data[i].total, 10)
    data[i].per_capita = parseInt(data[i].per_capita, 10)
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This should help!

```js
var a = {
  per_capita: "125.8",
  total: "1007.2",
  year: "2009",
}

Object.keys(a).forEach(function(el){
  a[el] = parseInt(a[el])
})

console.log(a)
console.log(typeof a.total)
```

Comment: I tried using .values instead but it doesnt work, why so?

```Object.values(obj).forEach(el => el = parseInt(el))```

Answer (score 1):

All you did was the conversion, but you missed the assignment:

```
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    data[i].year = parseInt(data[i].year, 10)
    data[i].total = parseInt(data[i].total, 10)
    data[i].per_capita = parseInt(data[i].per_capita, 10)
}
```

The `parseInt` function returns the int value, it doesn't change the input variable.

Another thing - if you need the total number to be float you should use the `parseFloat` function and not the `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array and the object amd assign the integer value of the properties, you want.

```
data.forEach(function (a) {
    ['year', 'total', 'per_capita'].forEach(function (k) {
        a[k] = Math.floor(+a[k]);
    });
});
```